# How to compute multinomial confidence interval for proportion if some categories have fewer than 5 counts

Tags: confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution

I want to compute multinomial confidence intervals for proportions, and I was planning to use one of the methodologies listed [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.multinomial_proportions_confint.html).

> The goodman method [1] is based on approximating a statistic based on the multinomial as a chi-squared random variable. The usual recommendation is that this is valid if all the values in counts are greater than or equal to 5. There is no condition on the number of categories for this method.
>
> The sison-glaz method [2] approximates the multinomial probabilities, and evaluates that with a maximum-likelihood estimator. The first approximation is an Edgeworth expansion that converges when the number of categories goes to infinity, and the maximum-likelihood estimator converges when the number of observations (sum(counts)) goes to infinity. In their paper, Sison & Glaz demo their method with at least 7 categories, so len(counts) >= 7 with all values in counts at or above 5 can be used as a rule of thumb for the validity of this method. This method is less conservative than the goodman method (i.e. it will yield confidence intervals closer to the desired significance level), but produces confidence intervals of uniform width over all categories (except when the intervals reach 0 or 1, in which case they are truncated), which makes it most useful when proportions are of similar magnitude.

Both methodologies seem to require at least 5 counts for each one of the classes for which I have to estimate confidence intervals. However, a small set of classes that I have in the data has fewer than 5 counts. Is there a way to prepare the data (e.g. filtering smaller classes) without biasing the analysis?

**Edit**: One way I can think of modifying the data would be to sort all categories with fewer than 5 counts in an aggregate category ("Others"). In this way I would be able to account for their contribution, although without computing a confidence interval for each of these categories.

[1]: Goodman, L.A., “On simultaneous confidence intervals for multinomial proportions,” Technometrics, Vol. 7, No. 2, 1965, pp. 247-254.

[2]: Sison, Cristina P., and Joseph Glaz, “Simultaneous Confidence Intervals and Sample Size Determination for Multinomial Proportions,” Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 90, No. 429, 1995, pp. 366-369.